# How to execute a function for 5 seconds in swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am creating a game, this function is used as a power up to shrink the sprite. I want this function to execute for 5 seconds, and attach this 5 second timer to a label as a count down.
After the function ends, return the sprite to its original size.

The function just shrinks the node by setting the scale.

`func shrinkShip() { spaceShip.scale(to: CGSize(width: 60, height: 40)) }`

Comment: technically you are piggy backing two questions into one. these should have been asked as separate questions. with you showing what you have done to attempt this to start with. not asking people to do it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking with SpriteKit I would just do the following

```
func shrinkShip(duration: Double) { 

    let originalSize = spaceShip.size

    spaceShip.scale(to: CGSize(width: 60, height: 40)) 

    for x in 0..<Int(duration) {

        //increment the timer every 1 second for the duration
        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1 * Double(x))) {
            self.timerLabel.text = String(Int(duration) - x)
        }
    }
    self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration)) {
        //return the spaceship to full size
        self.spaceShip.scale(to: originalSize) 
        //hide the timer
        self.timerLabel.text = ""
        self.timerLabel.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, trying to implement this, getting an error ```Operator function '..<' requires that 'Double.Stride' ```

Comment: sorry, I wrote that off the cuff on my windows computer. I edited and plugged it into xcode and it works perfectly now

Comment: I changed the line where uit outputs the text to the label. now it goes backwards
 good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the view like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
        self.spaceShip.scale(to: CGSize(width: 60, height: 40))
},
completion: { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.spaceShip.transform = .identity // Reset your view
    }
})
```

Comment: spaceShip is a SKSpriteNode, cannot perform transform ... can I just re-scale it back to the original size ? Instead of doing the ```transform = .identity```

Comment: ```completion: { self.spaceShip.scale(original)} ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
        self.spaceShip.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 60, y: 40)
},
completion: { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.spaceShip.transform = .identity // Reset your view
    }
})
```